# Program that listens for connections in background and also waits for user input

Tags: go, networking, blocking

I want to create a program that waits for user input and at the same time, listens for connections in the background. Neither of my functions depends on the other. I'm new to Go so I'm not sure how I can accomplish this. Can this even be done?

```golang
func listen() {
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp4", ":" + port)
    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        // Some stuff
    }
}


func getNewTransaction() {
    for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("Receiver: ")
        receiver, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        var amount float32
        fmt.Println("Amount: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%f", &amount)

    }
}


func main() {
    go listen()
    go getNewTransaction()

    select{}
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can be done in the way you illustrated already. Did you run into problems with this approach?

Comment: Yes, I get stuck in the listen function. The other function never runs.

Comment: What is the value of `port`?

Comment: How are you stuck? Any errors? One thing you might do is that once you accept a connection, you should start a new goroutine to process that connection while the listen() function should go back to listening.

Comment: But I want the whole listen function to run in the background. Right now, the whole program gets stuck on the listener.Accept() and keeps waiting until a new connection is made. The other function is not run during the waiting.

Comment: You are ignoring the error from net.Listen. You shouldn't.

Comment: I tried to print the error but no error is occurring.

Comment: How do you know it is stuck at Accept()? After a few edits, I can run this without problems.

Comment: Ok I figured it out and it was pretty dumb of me. The receiver string was being printed somewhere else and I thought it was stuck whereas it was just waiting for the user input. Thanks for all the help man!

Comment: The function`getNewTransaction` discards a bufio.Reader and possibly buffered data on every iteration of the loop.  Create the bufio.Reader outside the loop to avoid discarding buffered data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't show how the `port` is being available inside the `listen` function. So I am pretty sure the code is erroring out in that function.

I updated the `listen` function, and the one that takes user input. Replaces the `select{}` with wait group.

Here's working code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func listen(port string) {
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp4", ":"+port)
    defer listener.Close()

    fmt.Println("Telnet to: ", port)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            conn.Write([]byte("kthx bye!"))
        }

        conn.Close()

    }
}

func getNewTransaction() {
    for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("Type something and press enter: ")
        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        fmt.Println(input)
    }
}

func main() {
    go listen("8080")
    go getNewTransaction()

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually taking the port as a command line argument so I didn't think it was necessary to include it. The code was working fine, I was just misinterpreting the output.